# Send Email over Gmail API using Firebase Functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a Firebase function called `sendEmail` which is capable of sending E-Mail via my Google Workspace E-Mail account. I am able to call this function via:

```js
const sendEmailFn = httpsCallable(functions, 'sendEmail');
const response = await sendEmailFn({ email, subject, message });
```

The code of the function in the `index.js` file is shown as follows:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {google} = require("googleapis");

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
);

const gmailClient = new google.gmail({
  version: "v1",
  auth: oAuth2Client,
});

// Firebase Cloud Function to send an email
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const {email, subject, message} = data;

  // Construct the email content
  const emailContent = `
    From: "Sender Name" <email@example.com>
    To: "Recipient Name" <${email}>
    Subject: ${subject}
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

    ${message}
  `;

  try {
    // Send the email using the Gmail API
    await gmailClient.users.messages.send({
      userId: "me",
      requestBody: {
        raw: Buffer.from(emailContent).toString("base64"),
      },
    });

    return {success: true};
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        "An error occurred while sending the email.",
    );
  }
});
```

When calling this function as defined above the Logs suggest the following Error:

> I stell get Error sending email: Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.

When setting a API-Key to the `oAuth2Client` like:

```js
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
  // Set your API key as the access token
  access_token: "YOUR_API_KEY",
});
```

I get the error:

> message: 'Invalid Credentials'

Also when not using the `oAuth2Client` and setting directly the API-Key in the `gmail.auth` the API call get made, but there is a `401 Response`.

In the Gmail-API settings in the Google Console there are no possibilities to add such an API-Key so only `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` and `Service Accounts` are shown and allowed to use this API.

So how can I properly use the `oAuth2Client` to send Emails from my Google Workspace account using a React App with Firebase Functions.

**Edit 1:**
When using a service account in the following manner:

```js
// Create an OAuth2 client using the service account credentials
const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
  email: keyFile.client_email,
  key: keyFile.private_key,
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"],
});

// Set the credentials on the OAuth2 client
authClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Error authenticating:", err);
    throw new Error("Failed to authenticate");
  } else {
    console.log("Authentication successful");
  }
});
```

I am now able to authenticate, but now another error rises:

> Code: 400, message: 'Precondition check failed.'

Is the response the problem and I should change to something other than `me`? I have tried everything in this code:

```js
const response = await gmailClient.users.messages.send({
  userId: "me",
  requestBody: createMessage,
});
```

Comment: use a service account

Comment: Can you may be more specific how I could accomplish this?

Comment: currently you are using web credentials which will require a user authorize the app before it can run.   If you use a service account you can impersonation any user on your domain without requiring they authorize the app